# How can I change the site file directory for an apache server? (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

Right now it's '/var/www/html' but I want it to be '/home/pi/FTP'

I can probably just change it in the config file, but i can't manage to find it, thank you in advance.

Comment: What about taking a look into the documentation? That is what it is for, actually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to edit apache2.conf and 000-default.conf to change the document root of apache.

The Apache server is installed on var/www/html.This is the default root directory of apache.

Either change the root directory of Apache or move the project to /var/www/html.

To change Apache's root directory, run:

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

Then open the 000-default.conf file using the command:

```
nano 000-default.conf
```

Edit the DocumentRoot option:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/my/project
```

Then restart the apache server:

sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question, but i ran into an issue, when i try to go to my website now, it sais "403 Forbidden".

Comment: yeah you'll need to adjust the permissions of the directory you're pointing apache to in order to match /var/www/

Comment: I set it to drwxr-xr-x, but i still get the same error message

Comment: what about chown

Comment: I own the file, do i need to set the user to root?

Comment: set the user to whatever user owns /var/www/html

Comment: Are you requesting a specific file? Or expecting a list of files? My recollection is that a list request gets a 403 from Apache HTTP unless listing is specifically enabled.

Comment: Nvm i got it working. The owner of the FTP folder was a virtual user (for ftp) so apache couldn't access it